# New forms - embedding a collection of forms - Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm doing the same as explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

But in my case I want to add new "tags" not manually with clicking on a link, but automatically. I give to my template an array with items and for each of this items I want to add a new form - the number of items should be equal to the number of forms.

If it's possible, I'd prefer a solution like this:

```
{% for i in items %}

    {{ i.name }} {{ form_widget(form.tags[loop.index0].name) }}

{% endfor %}
```

But how to automatically create objects in the controller, too? It tells me that there is no obeject with  index=1, and yes - there isn't, but isn't there a way to create them automatically and not need to create for example 10 empty objects of the same kind in my controller? :(

---

Another thing I was thinking was something like this:

```
{% for i in items %}

 <ul class="orders" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.orders.vars.prototype)|e }}">

{{ i.name }} and here should be a field from the form, for example tag.name

 </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

I suggest that the js given in the cookbook should be changed to do this, but I'm not good in js and my tries didn't do the job.

I tried putting this in the loop:

```
<script>
   addTagForm(collectionHolder);
</script>
```

and this in a .js file:

```
var collectionHolder = $('ul.orders');

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   collectionHolder.data('index', collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

   function addTagForm(collectionHolder) {

    var prototype = collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    var index = collectionHolder.data('index');

    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
    collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
}

});
```

Comment: In my case, I needed only 10 objects (always) so I created them empty from the controller and passed them to the view. But in the case you don't know in advance, not sure this would be a good solution...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your main class has addTag($tag) method, you can add different 'new' tags to it.

*In class Task*

```
public function addTag($tag){
    $this->tags[]=$tag;

    return $this;
}
```

*In your Controller* (assuming 10 tags here)

```
$task=new Task();
for($i=0;i<10;i++){
   $task->addTag(new Tag());
}
$form->setData($task);
```

*In your view*

```
{% for tag in form.tags %}
 <ul class="orders">
    <li>{{ form_widget(tag.name) }}</li>
 </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't need the manually click, you can remove the JavaScript part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wanted to avoid the part of manually creating new Tags in the controller, bacause their number vary every time and most of the time they will be around 40-50. Of course, if there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: you can also place it in the formtype instead of controller, then when creating the form, you could do something like new TaskType(50);